Creating a simple XML with XML.jl in Julia lang
can someone  give a code to create a simple XML with XML.jl
let's have this example
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people>
    <Person>
        <name>Charlie9226</name>
        <age>38</age>
        <city>Los Angeles</city>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <name>Charlie9228</name>
        <age>46</age>
                <city>New York</city>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <name>Alice1447</name>
        <age>22</age>
        <city>New York</city>
    </Person>
</people>

But need to know how to create the Node, the Children, the Root. I will use it with a for loop. Thanks.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people>
    <Person>
        <name>Charlie9226</name>
        <age>38</age>
        <city>Los Angeles</city>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <name>Charlie9228</name>
        <age>46</age>
                <city>New York</city>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <name>Alice1447</name>
        <age>22</age>
        <city>New York</city>
    </Person>
</people>


with XML v0.3.3
using XML
using XML: h

myxml=h.people(
            h.person(
                h.name("Charlie9226"),
                h.age(string(38)),
                h.city("Los Angeles")
            ),
            h.person(
                h.name("Charlie9228"),
                h.age(string(46)),
                h.city("New York")
            ),
            h.person(
                h.name("Alice1447"),
                h.age(string(22)),
                h.city("New York")
            )
        )
xmlv= """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n"""


println(xmlv*XML.write(myxml))

In the case you want to use a for-loop you can use push! as the documentation says.
